# How to create a bootable Ubuntu Linux (10.04) USB installation for Macintosh

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mac, usb, refit

I tried searching the Internet, but could not find a decent tutorial explaining how to create a bootable Ubuntu Linux (10.04) USB installation that could be run not only on a PC but also on Macs and MacBook Pros. In addition, I tried refit, but ended with "Missing operating system" error.

Here is basically the layout of my bootable under PC Ubuntu USB drive (using MBR):
Partition 1 (ext3, bootable) - Ubuntu Linux 32 bit, contains also grub2 bootloader.
Partition 2 (ext3) - Ubuntu Linux 64 bit.
Partition 3 (fat32) - contains data.

What would be the best way to enable this drive to boot under Mac OS X? And if refit has to be used, could I simply have one more partition on the USB drive containing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to boot from a 2GB USB stick on my Macbook Pro and a PC by following the instructions on Ubuntu's download page: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download.

Just choose the version options you want on the *Download* section and on the *Burn your CD or create a bootable USB stick* section, pick "USB stick" and the OS you're using to download & create the bootable stick. Finally, click the orange "Show me how" button to see the directions for that specific senario.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is for ubuntu 8, but I’m sure it’s more or less the same. [Install Ubuntu on Mac Pro](http://mindbat.com/2008/01/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-mac-pro/)

Comment: I don't believe this is what he asked for, this installs on the hard drive. The OP wanted a bootable USB drive.